# How to fix the score count of my Rock, Paper, Scissors game not showing up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to learn programming this week and made a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. However, there is one problem: when I draw, the score count shows:

```
username: 0, Bot: 0.
```

But when I win or lose, the score count just didn't show up at all, though the game continues to function perfectly, just without the correct score count.

```
import random
user_score = 0
bot_score = 0

def game(username, user_choice):
    options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    bot = random.choice(options)

global user_score
global bot_score

if user_choice == 'rock' and bot == 'scissors':
    print(username + ' played rock, I played scissors. You won. Nice!')
    user_score += 1
    return user_score
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice == 'rock' and bot == 'paper':
    print(username + ' played rock, I played paper. You lost. Haha, loser!')
    bot_score += 1
    return bot_score
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice == 'paper' and bot == 'scissors':
    print(username + ' played paper, I played scissors. You lost. Haha, loser!')
    bot_score += 1
    return bot_score
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice == 'paper' and bot == 'rock':
    print(username + ' played paper, I played rock. You won. Nice!')
    user_score += 1
    return user_score
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'paper':
    print(username + ' played scissors, I played paper. You won. Nice!')
    user_score += 1
    return user_score
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice == 'scissors' and bot == 'rocks':
    print(username + ' played scissors, I played rocks. You lost. Haha, loser!')
    bot_score += 1
    return bot_score
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice == bot:
    print("It's a draw, dang it!")
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
elif user_choice != 'scissors' and user_choice != 'paper' and user_choice != 'rock':
    print('Please enter a valid choice!')  
    print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))


print('Hello, welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. Enter your name to get started.')
name = input()

while True:  
    choice = input('Rock, Paper or Scissors?\n').lower().strip()
    game(name, choice)
    if input('Want to play again? Yes or No\n').lower().strip() == 'no':
        print('Goodbye. Press Enter to exit.' + 'Result: User: ' + user_score +' \nBot: '+bot_score)
        input()
        break
```

Expected: The score count works, adding 1 to user_score and bot_score each time a side wins.
Actual: Score count does not show up when user win or lose.

Comment: A tip to improve your code: try to extract code that is repeated in all the if-cases (like the score print) and remove the returns completely as they return different things and are not used. Good luck!

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. First of all stackoverflow is not for questions like ”why doesn’t my code work”, second: your code had a simple error that a read through would have caught and the solution will not help anyone but you, third: there is a stack exchange for code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com and lastly: even though you didn’t follow any of the community guidelines, you still got the help you wanted. Don’t be ungrateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply a thing you overlooked

```
 return user_score
print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
```

As you can see you have placed the return statement before the print statement so the print statement is ignored and only value is returned. It can be corrected by simply interchaning.

```
print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
 return user_score
```

hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

```
return bot_score
print('\n'+username+': '+str(user_score)+', Bot: '+str(bot_score))
```

you return before you print.
The return jumps out of the function, therefore the print will never be reached. 
It should work, when you print before you return

Comment: its the same as i said

Comment: @TalhaIsrar, Brunei might have drafting the answer at the same time as you. I don't think it matters.

Comment: With all due respect i think that there is no purpose in repeating the exact same answer but at the end of the day you are right it doesnt really matter :)

Comment: sry wrote it, when it wasn't answered and when it refreshed your answere was there, too